# Can I run an Android Application in Lubuntu with an i386 32 bit architecture PC?

Tags: lubuntu, android, virtualization

Let me tell you what I've tried so far:

- ARC Welder, not compatible with architecture.
- https://archon-runtime.github.io/ – I don't know what year this was developed but I convert the simplest apps with my mobile and they can't run. I'm trying to convert the one that I actually want and it crashes immediately. I'm talking about the second tool.
- https://anbox.io/ – I've got snapp installed, it can't find anything literaly.

  > error: snap "anbox-installer" not found

Got any ideas? How much difficult is it from a programmer/engineer point of view?

Answer (score 0):

I personally vote for Archon Runtime at the version 2.1. I run few applications like Shazam and Angry Birds on my desktop. You need to install Chrome and load the runtime as unpacked extension, then export the apk using archon packager (see play store for that).

The Anbox is not there yet. Simply it does not run my applications at this time.

Comment: Can you try to package 'Last Empire War Z'? Is it my device or it can't be done?

Comment: Last time I tried Android emulators on Linux left a bit to be desired.  They are complex to configure, slow as mud, and poor integration with Google play apps

Comment: I could not package it with Archon, but you can still package it using command line tool from Archon's github - at least give it a try. I could however replace the apk within an existing application, but it might have incorrect settings or missing some google play services. You can try to tweak it. I was not able to run it with virtualbox in an X86 Android. It is probably due to use of advanced 3D graphics the game is using...